# How to create a function to add css class for each first word with same letter from which it starts?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I did a list and search field on Wordpress. Search type works with post-types. I need to create a function, which should add my css class with Letter. It should be like on screenshot.
[image: It should looks like here]

My Code to show this list:

```
                <form class="antibodies-form" action="">
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"
                           placeholder="Search our Research Antibodies "></input>
                </form>

                <h3 class="antibodies-title">Research Antibodies</h3>
                <ul id="datafetch" class="antibodies-items">
                    <?php
                    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']), 'post_type' => 'antibodies'));
                    if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                        while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url(post_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                        <?php endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    endif;

                    ?>
```

My span element with specific class which will add this letter: It should be inside

element.

```
<span class="antibodies-item-letter">A</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an empty variable as the current index and then loop through your posts. On each iteration you can get the first character of the title via `substr( get_the_title(), 0, 1 )`.

If the current index does not match the first character, make the current index equal to the first character and add an extra span to the `<li>` containing the current index.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
    'post_type'         => 'antibodies',
    'order'             => 'ASC', 
    'orderby'           => 'title',
    's'                 => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
));
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $current_index = '';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $first_char = substr( get_the_title(), 0, 1 );
        if ( $current_index !== $first_char ) {
            $current_index = $first_char;
            printf( '<li><span class="antibodies-item-letter">%s</span><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $current_index, get_permalink(), get_the_title() );
        } else {
            printf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_permalink(), get_the_title() );
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. If this was useful to you, you can also upvote the answer.